# Is there a way to setup a sink and source connector for this debezium connector?

Tags: apache-kafka, docker-compose, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I'm using the debezium-connector found here: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/debezium/debezium-connector-oracle/1.4.0.Final/debezium-connector-oracle-1.4.0.Final-plugin.tar.gz

And I'm following these instructions for docker-compose: https://github.com/confluentinc/demo-scene/blob/master/oracle-and-kafka/docker-compose.yml

I did it for jdbc-connector by using confluent-hub but I don't know how to do it for debezium. It's not solved by adding it into /usr/share/java and running

So my docker-compose is:

```
    ---
version: '2'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:6.0.1
    hostname: zookeeper
    container_name: zookeeper
    volumes:
      - /dados/persistence/zookeeper/data:/var/lib/zookeeper/data
      - /dados/persistence/zookeeper/log:/var/lib/zookeeper/log
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000

  kafka:
    image: confluentinc/cp-server:6.0.1
    hostname: broker
    container_name: broker
    volumes:
      - /dados/persistence/broker/data:/var/lib/kafka/data
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
      - "9101:9101"
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://broker:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9092
      KAFKA_METRIC_REPORTERS: io.confluent.metrics.reporter.ConfluentMetricsReporter
      KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE: "true"
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: 0
      KAFKA_CONFLUENT_LICENSE_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_CONFLUENT_BALANCER_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_JMX_PORT: 9101
      KAFKA_JMX_HOSTNAME: localhost
      KAFKA_CONFLUENT_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: http://schema-registry:8081
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: kafka:29092
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_TOPIC_REPLICAS: 1
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_ENABLE: 'true'
      CONFLUENT_SUPPORT_CUSTOMER_ID: 'anonymous'

  schema-registry:
    image: confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:6.0.1
    hostname: schema-registry
    container_name: schema-registry
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
      - kafka
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    environment:
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME: schema-registry
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_CONNECTION_URL: zookeeper:2181

  kafka-connect:
    image: cnfldemos/cp-server-connect-datagen:0.4.0-6.0.1
    hostname: connect
    container_name: kafka-connect
    volumes:
      - /dados/packages/confluent-hub/share/confluent-hub-components:/usr/share/confluent-hub-components/custom
      - /dados/persistence/kafka-connect/jars:/etc/kafka-connect/jars
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
      - kafka
      - schema-registry
    ports:
      - "8083:8083"
    environment:
      CONNECT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'kafka:29092'
      CONNECT_REST_PORT: 8083
      CONNECT_GROUP_ID: compose-connect-group
      CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-connect-configs
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-connect-offsets
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-connect-status
      CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER: org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER: io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: 'http://schema-registry:8081'
      CONNECT_INTERNAL_KEY_CONVERTER: "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter"
      CONNECT_INTERNAL_VALUE_CONVERTER: "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter"
      CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: "kafka-connect"
      CONNECT_LOG4J_ROOT_LOGLEVEL: "INFO"
      CONNECT_LOG4J_APPENDER_STDOUT_LAYOUT_CONVERSIONPATTERN: "[%d] %p %X{connector.context}%m (%c:%L)%n"
      CONNECT_LOG4J_LOGGERS: "org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest=WARN,org.reflections=ERROR"
      CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: "1"
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: "1"
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: "1"
      CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH: "/usr/share/java,/usr/share/confluent-hub-components,/usr/share/confluent-hub-components/custom"
      LD_LIBRARY_PATH: '/usr/share/java/debezium-connector-oracle/instantclient_19_6/'

  control-center:
    image: confluentinc/cp-enterprise-control-center:6.0.1
    hostname: control-center
    container_name: control-center
    depends_on:
      - kafka
      - schema-registry
      - kafka-connect
      - ksqldb
    ports:
      - "9021:9021"
    environment:
      CONTROL_CENTER_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'kafka:29092'
      CONTROL_CENTER_CONNECT_CLUSTER: 'kafka-connect:8083'
      CONTROL_CENTER_KSQL_KSQLDB1_URL: "http://10.58.0.207:8088"
      CONTROL_CENTER_KSQL_KSQLDB1_ADVERTISED_URL: "http://10.58.0.207:8088"
      CONTROL_CENTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: "http://10.58.0.207:8081"
      CONTROL_CENTER_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONTROL_CENTER_INTERNAL_TOPICS_PARTITIONS: 1
      CONTROL_CENTER_MONITORING_INTERCEPTOR_TOPIC_PARTITIONS: 1
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_TOPIC_REPLICATION: 1
      PORT: 9021

  ksqldb:
    image: confluentinc/cp-ksqldb-server:6.0.1
    hostname: ksqldb
    container_name: ksqldb-server
    depends_on:
      - kafka
      - kafka-connect
    ports:
      - "8088:8088"
    environment:
      KSQL_CONFIG_DIR: "/etc/ksql"
      KSQL_LISTENERS: "http://0.0.0.0:8088"
      KSQL_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: kafka:29092
      KSQL_KSQL_LOGGING_PROCESSING_STREAM_AUTO_CREATE: "true"
      KSQL_KSQL_LOGGING_PROCESSING_TOPIC_AUTO_CREATE: "true"
      KSQL_KSQL_CONNECT_URL: http://kafka-connect:8083
      KSQL_KSQL_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: http://schema-registry:8081

  ksqldb-cli:
    image: confluentinc/cp-ksqldb-cli:6.0.1
    container_name: ksqldb-cli
    depends_on:
      - kafka
      - kafka-connect
      - ksqldb
    entrypoint: /bin/sh
    tty: true

  ksql-datagen:
    image: confluentinc/ksqldb-examples:6.0.1
    hostname: ksql-datagen
    container_name: ksql-datagen
    depends_on:
      - ksqldb
      - kafka
      - schema-registry
      - kafka-connect
    command: "bash -c 'echo Waiting for Kafka to be ready... && \
                       cub kafka-ready -b broker:29092 1 40 && \
                       echo Waiting for Confluent Schema Registry to be ready... && \
                       cub sr-ready schema-registry 8081 40 && \
                       echo Waiting a few seconds for topic creation to finish... && \
                       sleep 11 && \
                       tail -f /dev/null'"
    environment:
      KSQL_CONFIG_DIR: "/etc/ksql"
      STREAMS_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: kafka:29092
      STREAMS_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST: schema-registry
      STREAMS_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_PORT: 8081

  rest-proxy:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka-rest:6.0.1
    depends_on:
      - kafka
      - schema-registry
    ports:
      - 8082:8082
    hostname: rest-proxy
    container_name: rest-proxy
    environment:
      KAFKA_REST_HOST_NAME: rest-proxy
      KAFKA_REST_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'kafka:29092'
      KAFKA_REST_LISTENERS: "http://0.0.0.0:8082"
      KAFKA_REST_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: 'http://schema-registry:8081'
```

Comment: You have a mounted path `/etc/kafka-connect/jars`, but are not using that in `CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `/etc/kafka-connect/jars` to `CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH`

Comment: The only "jars" I found are: /var/lib/docker/overlay2/ad6e90f2efe793f95c252a584d4ef8188e477187b66e095d1cc7a92c3a7d78ef/diff/etc/kafka-connect/jars
/var/lib/docker/overlay2/ab6f295bc1bbc45caf41ffc7eefcfd43c7cf975ad51fb130e5f1f7298b9d3485/merged/etc/kafka-connect/jars
/dados/persistence/kafka-connect/jars                                                                                                 The first and second ones are images downloaded when I run "docker-compose up -d". The last one is from a persistence directory I created to redirect data from broker, kafka-connect and zookeeper

Comment: Where have you put your Debezium jar? Is that in a folder local on your host machine?

Comment: I've put it in "/usr/share/java". It's in "debezium-connector-oracle" folder. But I've already added "usr/share/java" on my docker-compose file

Comment: I don't quite follow (and comments thread isn't best for this). Can you edit your question to clearly state which local folder you have the Debezium JAR in? I'm assuming that you've mounted that folder to your Docker container?